# Allow uppercase table name linux webserver

Tags: c#, mysql, linux, webserver

I have made an application in C# with a MySql backend. While we are running the application on windows server everything is okay, but now my client requires the database to be online, the hosted website is on a Linux server.

The problem is I have written  all my tables in CAPITAL letters in all queries in C# and the Linux server returns an error about the table not being found.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Its a solution for win7-apachi 2.2.11-php 5.3-mysql 5.1.36

1- Go to your my.ini file of your MySQLand add this line at the end1 
    lower_case_table_names=2
    This tells MySQL to preserve cases for table names. This file should be located in your bin directory of your MySQL install folder

2- Restart your MySQL

3- Now simply go to phpmyadmin, rename the table to any temp name, then rename the temp name back to the original with upper case.